# Telerik "Live Demos" solution - connection strings & database setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, telerik, rad-controls

Looking for a person who's setup the Telerik Rad Controls for ASP.NET AJAX Live Demos project before... I recently downloaded the Telerik Rad Controls for ASP.NET AJAX framework.  I'm in the process of upgrading some of our company's code using the Telerik Rad Controls for ASP.NET (non-AJAX) framework from about 5-6 years ago to the new AJAX framework.  Many of the old controls don't work in the latest browser releases (Google Chrome 12, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer).  Some controls work in some browsers but not others, and sometimes it's not always the same browser where it broke.

I did the best I could to fix the existing issues from our company's framework, but we still have some remaining issues, previously posted as questions by me.  Those are what I'm trying to fix.  So then I proceeded to get the demo project installed.

Our company doesn't use Visual Studio 2010 yet, so yesterday, I downgraded the Telerik Live Demos project to Visual Studio 2008.  I manually converted the *.sln file by making 3 changes.  Luckily there wasn't a *.csproj/*.vbproj files (obviously since they have both languages in their website project).  I then changed the .NET version from 4.0 to 3.5, made the necessary Bin35 updates to the web site bin folder, removed 4 different .NET 4.0 dlls in the project and unloaded any files using those assemblies, made the necessary changes in IIS 7, compiled the solution and all was well....

Until I tried to view some of the controls.  I then discovered they have 2 databases (Northwind & Telerik) you need to download (*.mdf/*.ldf files) and Attach to SQL Server 2008.  I did that today, updated the connection strings, but I'm still having an issue.  I'm hoping this is the last of many issues I need to fix to get this working so I can understand the framework.

FYI: I'm using the web.config.35 file as my "web.config" file right now.  I also changed the solution/project's .NET version from 2.0 to 3.5.  Is this okay?  I figured it would be since 2.0 dlls can still function okay in a 3.5 site.. since it's still the 2.0 architecture.

Can someone explain to me what all of these connections strings are for and the necessary setup?  I have the *.mdf and *.ldf files attached to SQL Server, but they are still in integrated mode (for access).  I also renamed the databases... after attaching and adding the *.mdf files, the database names were REALLY LONG!

**web.config connection strings:**

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="NorthwindConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="TelerikConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Telerik.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="NorthwindConnectionString35" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="TelerikConnectionString35" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Telerik.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Northwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="TelerikEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Telerik.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="QSFRatingsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|QSFRatings.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="SelfReferencingDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|TelerikSelfReferencingDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

**Still getting this error when viewing the ComboBox control in the Live Demos (when running the Live Demos website):**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849015
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2394
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +144
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +342
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +221
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +4863459
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +433
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState& originalState) +31
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +112
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +287
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +92
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1297
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +19
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +635
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformSelect() +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.DataBind() +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +22
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4961; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have admin credentials that allow your APP to attach the .mdf files to SQL server, set User Instance = false (**Edit: change this to false in your connection strings**).

I would assume that is why you are currently getting that error you see above. Not saying this will completely fix all of your problems, but it should help you with that error.

-Hope that helps
-J

Comment: posted a new question based on this one.. since this didn't completely solve my issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366295/sqlexpress-connection-fails-in-iis-7-w-user-instance-error-failed-to-generate

Comment: Responding here so I don't clog up that fresh post, but you mention that you are logged in as "Network Service" user under SQL server. Have you tried to use the Local System (under Log On tab in SQL Server properties tab) yet? And if so, what were the results?

Comment: absolutely.. let me check what the error was (if I recall.. same error)

Comment: yep, same error .. looks like you know quite a bit about Rad Controls.  if you need me to show you more about my setup, let me know

Comment: Yea, all my apps/sites have been using Telerik controls since I entered my current position. Down side is that it's not always the controls fault, but instead some goofy setting in IIS or SQL. You got access to any sort of chat (google chat or anything?) software where you work? Might make it easier to help.